# How can I select items from my table in to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How can I get the results from my data reader into a `List<String>`?

Here is my code so far:

```
public List<string> Item_Getall()
{
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("c_get_all_item",oo.conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oo.conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        data.Add(rdr["item_name_id_pk"].ToString());
        data.Add(rdr["item_name_arabic"].ToString());
        data.Add(rdr["item_componant"].ToString());
        data.Add(rdr["item_componant_arabic"].ToString());
        data.Add(rdr["item_price"].ToString());
        data.Add(rdr["item_image"].ToString());
        data.Add(rdr["item_category_name_id_fk"].ToString());
    }
    oo.conn.Close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: as a start, use a class for your table.add a property for each column, then use `List<YourClass>` instead of `List<string>`

Comment: As a side note, you should have `using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) { //your code }`.

Comment: It looks like you're already doing what you're asking.  Is this not working in some way?  At the very least, you're breaking up each record into multiple entries in the `List<>`, which is certainly odd.  But if this is what you're trying to do, how is it not working for you?

Comment: I hope further clarification

Comment: @PatrickHofman 

i selected this method in gridview by using objectDataSourse 

the result --> column called "lenght"
i didn't understand !!

Answer (score 2):

You better use your custom type list instead of string and store your custom type object in list

```
List<YourCustomType> data = new List<YourCustomType>();
```

Custom type

```
public class YourCustom
{
     public string ItemName {get; set;}
     //Similarly all the properties.
}
```

Reading values from data Reader and adding in Custom Type List

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    data.Add(new YourCustom()
    {
       Id = rdr["item_name_id_pk"].ToString(),
       Name = rdr["item_name_arabic"].ToString()
       //Similarly all other properties could be set 
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the meaning of " custom type"

Comment: A user defined type, public class YourCustom, Give it name which best describes your Entity (Type)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to create a custom class and return a list of this class:

```
public class Item
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Reading would go as:

```
var data = new List<Item>();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    data.Add(new Item()
    {
        Id = int.Parse(rdr["item_name_id_pk"]),
        Name = rdr["item_name_arabic"].ToString()
    }
}
return data;
```

Also, look into the using() statement which will make your code more robust in the eye of exceptions during database calls.

Comment: what's the keyword " var "?
what 's it used for !!

var data = new List<Item>();

Comment: This is called [type inference](http://joelabrahamsson.com/a-neat-little-type-inference-trick-with-c/). It as the same as writing `List<Item> data = new List<Item>();`

Comment: ok , thanks
sorry ,but i have anthor question , can you explain " data.Add(new Item()"

Comment: This is called [property initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) it is an alternative to providing constructor overloads. It is the same as writing: `var item = new Item(); item.Id = 5; item.Name = "nam"`

Comment: i selected this method by objectdatasource in gridview , but the gridview appeared empty

Comment: In most Grids, you need to add columns and specify which property should be displayed for each column. So in this example you'd have columns for "Id" and "Name". (How it works exactly depends on the Grid - be it a web, winforms, wpf, ... grid)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788344/i-selected-this-method-by-objectdatasource-in-gridview-but-the-gridview-appear

Comment: coulmns of the table is appeare .. but didn't selected data from database

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataAdapter and a custom type:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("c_get_all_item",oo.conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
oo.conn.Open();

var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dt;
adapter.Fill(dt);

oo.Close()

//Convert DataTable to a list of YourType
List<YourType> data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(s=> 
                         new YourType { 
                          item_name_id_pk = s.Field<FieldDataType>("item_name_id_pk"),
                          item_name_arabic = s.Field<FieldDataType>("item_name_arabic"),
                             ...
                         })
                         .ToList();
```

Your custom type would be like;

```
public class YourType
{
    //Replace the DataType with correct datatype to match with FieldDataType
    public DataType item_name_id_pk {get; set;}
    public DataType item_name_arabic {get; set;}
    ...
}
```