# i selected this method by objectdatasource in gridview , but the gridview appeared empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i selected this method by objectdatasource in gridview , but the gridview appeared empty
![enter image description here][1]

[1]:gridview photo.jpg

```
public List<Item> Item_Getall()
{
    List<Item> data = new List<Item>();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("c_get_all_item",oo.conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oo.conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        data.Add(new Item());
        {
            Name_id = (rdr["item_name_id_pk"].ToString());
            Name_arabic = (rdr["item_name_arabic"].ToString());
            Component_english = (rdr["item_componant"].ToString());
            Component_arabic = (rdr["item_componant_arabic"].ToString());
            Price = float.Parse(rdr["item_price"].ToString());
            Image = (rdr["item_image"].ToString());
            Category = (rdr["item_category_name_id_fk"].ToString());
        }
    }
    oo.conn.Close();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Try `data.Add(new Item(){/*Your asignment code*/});`

Comment: Yeah, there is that. The code listed above wont actually compile, but im assuming his code is different because he said the gridview doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE - Try to make my answer more helpful**

If you want to simply bind your data to a gridview, it is very easy to do it on the backend. Lets say you do it in the Page_Load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, eventArgs e){

    var data = Item_Getall(); //Creates a list of items by calling your method.

    gridView.DataSource = data; //assuming the ID of your gridview is "gridView". It might be something different.

    gridView.DataBind(); //binds the data to your grid. If you have it set to auto populate, it should essentially list out every public property for each object in the list.

}
```

Comment: what do you mean about data? .. do you mean list name ?

Comment: Updated my answer with more details

Comment: i have the error

Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView_show_items'.  Remove one definition.